# Should I release simple NSString in dealloc

Tags: nsstring, release, dealloc

I have in .h:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *myString;
```

In .m:

```
@synthesize myString;
myString =@"Test";
```

Do I have to release it in dealloc?
Because sometimes my app crashes due to [myString release], not sure why?

Comment: It can't be arc as long as he's using the "retain" attribute. Otherwise it would be strong/weak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the property is defined with the "retain" attribute, it needs to be released in the dealloc.

ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) in modern Objective C has built-in garbage collection, so releasing and retaining are no longer necessary.

Comment: reference counting != garbage collection